# How to use boost graph to traverse a planar graph ( representing a tree ) to simulate walking around the edge of the graph

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I have the following graph on the XY plane. Vertices are numbered. I have

```
struct Point {
  double x;
  double y;
}

std::vector<Point> points;
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> edges;
```

For example I may have 6 vertices and 5 edges

[image]

I wish to choose any vertex to start my traversal. Let's choose *vertex 1*. The traversal would be.

- 1
- 3
- 6
- 4
- 6
- 5
- 6
- 3
- 2
- 3
- 1

This is equivalent to treating the graph like a fence in a field and walking along the fence clockwise keeping the wall to your right hand side.

[image]

I believe this is the planar traversal as described in

[https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html#:~:text=A%20traversal%20of%20the%20faces,the%20border%20of%20the%20face](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html#:%7E:text=A%20traversal%20of%20the%20faces,the%20border%20of%20the%20face).

However boost graph requires a precalculated planar embedding which requires pre-sorting all the edges around each vertex. I didn't see a way within the boost library to perform this sorting automatically. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to automatically get the planar embedding is as [the output from a planarity test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_graphs.html). So you could wrap that in your own function:

```
template <typename G> void walk_faces(G const& g) {
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    using E = G::edge_descriptor;

    // edge index
    std::map<E, size_t> e_index;
    for (size_t edge_count = 0; auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        e_index[e] = edge_count++;

    // compute the planar embedding
    using Edges = std::vector<E>;
    std::vector<Edges> embedding(num_vertices(g));
    auto embedmap = make_safe_iterator_property_map( //
        embedding.begin(), embedding.size(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    namespace P = boost::boyer_myrvold_params;
    if (!boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(P::graph = g, P::embedding = embedmap))
        std::runtime_error("not a planar graph");

    struct : boost::planar_face_traversal_visitor {
        void begin_face()     const { std::cout << "New face: "; }
        void end_face()       const { std::cout << std::endl; }
        void next_vertex(V v) const { std::cout << v << " "; }
    } vis;

    planar_face_traversal(g, embedmap, vis, make_assoc_property_map(e_index));
}
```

Demo: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe02a30c64f5f926)**:

```
New face: 1 3 2 3 6 5 6 4 6 3
```

### UPDATE: Clockwise ordering

After reading the comments, I figured out a way to apply a siilar clock-wise ordering:

```
for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
    std::ranges::sort( //
        g.out_edge_list(v), std::less{}, [src = g[v], &g](auto const& out) {
            auto& dst = g[out.get_iter()->m_target];
            return atan2(dst.y - src.y, dst.x - src.x);
        });
```

Note how I didn't take the angle from a fixed starting point¹, instead actually sorting by the angle of each individual edge. I'll leave it to you to decide whether that's okay for you. It seemed to be enough for the given example.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c08eaea3c29f4e10)**

```cpp
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boyer_myrvold_planar_test.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/planar_face_traversal.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template <typename G>
void walk_faces(G const& g) {
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    using E = G::edge_descriptor;

    // edge index
    std::map<E, size_t> e_index;
    for (size_t edge_count = 0; auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        e_index[e] = edge_count++;

    // compute the planar embedding
    using Edges = std::vector<E>;
    std::vector<Edges> embedding(num_vertices(g));
    auto embedmap = make_safe_iterator_property_map( //
        embedding.begin(), embedding.size(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    namespace P = boost::boyer_myrvold_params;
    if (!boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(P::graph = g, P::embedding = embedmap))
        std::runtime_error("not a planar graph");

    struct : boost::planar_face_traversal_visitor {
        void begin_face()     const { std::cout << "New face: "; }
        void end_face()       const { std::cout << std::endl; }
        void next_vertex(V v) const { std::cout << v << " "; }
    } vis;

    planar_face_traversal(g, embedmap, vis, make_assoc_property_map(e_index));
}

int main() {
    struct Point {
        double x, y;
    };
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Point>;
    G g;

    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(3, 6, g);
    add_edge(3, 2, g);
    add_edge(6, 4, g);
    add_edge(6, 5, g);

    g[1] = {-1, -1};
    g[2] = {+1, -1};
    g[3] = {+0, +0};
    g[4] = {-1, +3};
    g[5] = {+1, +3};
    g[6] = {+0, +2};

    std::cout << "Before: ";
    walk_faces(g);

    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        std::ranges::sort( //
            g.out_edge_list(v), std::less{}, [src = g[v], &g](auto const& out) {
                auto& dst = g[out.get_iter()->m_target];
                return atan2(dst.y - src.y, dst.x - src.x);
            });

    std::cout << "After:  ";
    walk_faces(g);
}
```

Which now prints:

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boyer_myrvold_planar_test.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/planar_face_traversal.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template <typename G>
void walk_faces(G const& g) {
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    using E = G::edge_descriptor;

    // edge index
    std::map<E, size_t> e_index;
    for (size_t edge_count = 0; auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        e_index[e] = edge_count++;

    // compute the planar embedding
    using Edges = std::vector<E>;
    std::vector<Edges> embedding(num_vertices(g));
    auto embedmap = make_safe_iterator_property_map( //
        embedding.begin(), embedding.size(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    namespace P = boost::boyer_myrvold_params;
    if (!boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(P::graph = g, P::embedding = embedmap))
        std::runtime_error("not a planar graph");

    struct : boost::planar_face_traversal_visitor {
        void begin_face()     const { std::cout << "New face: "; }
        void end_face()       const { std::cout << std::endl; }
        void next_vertex(V v) const { std::cout << v << " "; }
    } vis;

    planar_face_traversal(g, embedmap, vis, make_assoc_property_map(e_index));
}

int main() {
    struct Point {
        double x, y;
    };
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Point>;
    G g;

    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(3, 6, g);
    add_edge(3, 2, g);
    add_edge(6, 4, g);
    add_edge(6, 5, g);

    g[1] = {-1, -1};
    g[2] = {+1, -1};
    g[3] = {+0, +0};
    g[4] = {-1, +3};
    g[5] = {+1, +3};
    g[6] = {+0, +2};

    std::cout << "Before: ";
    walk_faces(g);

    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        std::ranges::sort( //
            g.out_edge_list(v), std::less{}, [src = g[v], &g](auto const& out) {
                auto [x, y] = g[out.get_iter()->m_target];
                return atan2(y - src.y, x - src.x);
            });

    std::cout << "After:  ";
    walk_faces(g);
}
```

Now prints:

```
Before: New face: 1 3 2 3 6 5 6 4 6 3 
After:  New face: 1 3 6 4 6 5 6 3 2 3
```

---

¹ I suppose the selection using `min_element` may be ambiguous, by the way. It seems that in your question example both points 1 and 4 have equally minimal x?

Comment: You don't sort by the point coordinates. Swapping vertex 1 and 2 or swapping 4 and 5 and you still have a planar graph but the the order of the traversal would be different. The solution requires sorting the edges around each vertex. I ended up doing this and it turned out simpler to avoid boost. My code correctly solves the white graph in the image with traversal following the order of the red line. https://i.imgur.com/vXsG53h.png My code is https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/c376a8778b99c1d3c006283f38ee55c9 ( not posted as a solution here as it doesn't really answer the question as asked )

Comment: But thankyou for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Ah. So your question REALLY wasn't about "However boost graph requires a precalculated planar embedding" but only about picking the **right** planar embedding. Yeah, that was too subtle for me to pick up. If the answer was helpful at all (it does show some simplications relative to the documentation example e.g.) I'd appreciate a vote, because right now the reward for my time is negative :)

Comment: Looking at your code: that looks pretty nice. I wonder what library `mw::seq` refers to. Also, I noticed I completely missed that the geometric layout of the graph was given. Therefore I didn't think there was any objective layout that implies a particular order (and I took the image as to describe a example path around an example layout). That's what I get for reading a question on my phone I guess. Sorry for that.

Comment: mw::seq is just an internal library I wrote. Basically like std::range.

Comment: I found a way to incorporate the ordering with the Boost approach just now. I still wager your own code is probably more efficient considering the requirements, but I hope you dislike my answer less now :)

Comment: Very nice! This is what I'm looking for. I probably will keep my own code but this is a nice example for others to find on how to use boost::graph to solve such a problem. One point. You have an off by one error. The result should be "1 3 6 4 6 5 6 3 2 3 1" rather than "1 3 6 4 6 5 6 3 2 3" though this seems to be a result of the way boost implements the *planar_face_traversal_visitor* function. I've marked the answer as correct but you might just want to check this one point.

Comment: With regards to (1) That min_element based on x is ambiguous.  I guess so. The point was that you are guaranteed that there is no edge further to the left. To make it non-ambiguous could base it on x and y.