# boost graphs - topological sort with priority

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'd like to do an altered topological sort. At any given level, there are a number of choices we can take.

[image]

For example, the topological order of this graph could be 1 -> 2 -> 3 or 2 -> 1 -> 3.

My vertices has data associated as such.

```
struct VertexData {
  int id;
  int weight;
}
```

I'd like the topological sort to prioritise higher weights first whenever encountering a choice. So the order will always be 2 -> 1 -> 3 in this case.

How can I do this?

Edit: I'm using Vecs for both Edge and VertexList

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try sorting the VertexData by weight?

Answer (score 0):

Everything rides on the choice of graph model here.

The algorithm does not provide an extension point for initial vertex ordering. It just gets the out edges using the vanilla concept:

```
boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges(u, g); // depth_first_search.hpp:L152
```

Any ordered/hashed container selector for `adjacency_list`'s `OutEdgeList`  parameter will compare only by the edge's target. All of this is implementation detail.

As long as you're not using an ordered/hashed container selector, you might interfere and sort those out-edges manually, like [I've showed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698392/85371).

In this case I might be mistaken but it looks like you can get away with sorting the vertices ahead of creating the edges:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed268c0dcde4d36b)**

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <ranges>
namespace r = std::ranges;
namespace v = std::views;

template <typename G> auto topo_order(G const& g) {
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    std::map<V, size_t> idx;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        idx.emplace(v, idx.size());

    std::deque<V> order;

    topological_sort(             //
        g, front_inserter(order), //
        vertex_index_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(idx)));

    return order;
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>

template <typename Cmp> void demo() {
    struct VertexData {
        int id;
        int weight;
    };
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, VertexData>;

    G g;
    auto v2 = add_vertex({2, 30}, g);
    auto v1 = add_vertex({1, 20}, g);
    auto v3 = add_vertex({3, 20}, g);

    g.m_vertices.sort([&g, cmp = Cmp{}](auto const& a, auto const& b) { //
        return cmp(g[a].weight, g[b].weight);
    });

    add_edge(v1, v3, g);
    add_edge(v2, v3, g);

    fmt::print("{} topo: {}\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
               topo_order(g) | v::transform([&g](auto v) { return g[v].id; }));
}

int main() {
    demo<r::less>();
    demo<r::greater>();
}
```

Printing

```
void demo() [with Cmp = std::ranges::less] topo: [2, 1, 3]
void demo() [with Cmp = std::ranges::greater] topo: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm using a VecS as both my Edge and VertexList - how can i modify this accordingly?

Comment: It’s probably becoming more complicated than fun: vector storage loses descriptor (and iterator/reference) stability, so sorting invalidates all you previously held descriptors. I’d say at that point you should probably attempt to order the vertices before ever adding them to the BGL graph model. Alternatively you might define a custom graph model. I’ve previously demonstrated how to do that, specifically allowing for e.g. an algorithm like topological sort: looks like this links should give you all the pointers and some background info all at once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361794/85371

Comment: (In case it wasn’t obvious, you can of course sort the vertices and then recalculate all the descriptors required by looking them up by property (`id`) but instinctively I’d draw the line there; if you *need* the contiguous storage semantics (why?) then I’d look for better options first, because what use is using C++ if you’re not going prioritize efficiency?)